# How do I use requirejs to load a static JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, requirejs

I want to keep a JSON document to store some simple data and I want to require this document and use the JSON object in a `define()` call so I can use it. This is not an `async` call. I mean it should be for development but I do want to compile the file on build unlike an actual `async` call from an API, where the content is dynamic.

Comment: Exactly what is your question then ? because i don't see any problem with that.

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer Well I'm not sure how I'm supposed to do it. I can't include a `.json` file in paths.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by using the requirejs json plugin for this, this will allow you to include your file into the build as well.

https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins
Here is an example:

```
require(['json!someFile.json'], function(data){
  ...
})
// It does not actually need to be a .json extension, this will work to:
require(['json!someFile'], function(data){
  ...
})
```

If you want to include the file in your r.js build so that it is always optimized in the main/js bootstrap file you have to add it to the include option

You could also use the require js text plugin for this, it's usually used to load template files but you can use it to load .json files as well.

https://github.com/requirejs/text

You will have to parse the contents your self then with `JSON.parse`
(Include [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to provide support for older browsers if that's required)

You could also wrap the json in it's own define() so you can just require it traditionally, but that won't work if you are limited to an actual `.json` file.

An other option is to require the text file trough ajax your self, with jquery or something.

```
$.get('somefile.json', function(data) {
  // do something with your data
});
```

Comment: I went with `requirejs-plugins` and it has a `json` plugin I totally overlooked. It uses `text` as a dependency though. So thanks! I just started working with requirejs today on the browser and it's awesome. I'm still hoping that when I build it's going to to stop using ajax to fetch the document.

Comment: @ThomasReggi check my adapted answer for info on that

Comment: I have trouble with using text! for JSON content when combined with r.js to optimize. Just a heads up.

Comment: @SimpleAsCouldBe Please elaborate on your troubles

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer I sometimes use `text!./colors.json`, then do a parse on it as a way to get config values. This worked in dev, but the r.js optimizer throws an error. I isolated it to that specific file, and when replaced with a standard module wrapped in an amd define like `./colors`, the optimizer no longer fails. I wasn't interested in getting to root cause, Just had to finish the job. Would be happy to talk offline if you'd like.

Comment: +1 for the "better option" of just defining an object module containing what would be the JSON object, if you are able to modify the original JSON as such.

Comment: @ThomasReggi the json plugin uses eval rather than json.parse; I wouldn't recommend using it. I'm going to try the noext plugin and then parse it with JSON.parse .

Comment: If you prefer to load json by using `define(['jquery','data.json'], function($, jsonData){...});` or `require(['jquery','data.json'], function($, jsonData){...});`, keep in mind, that `var parsedJson = $.parseJSON(jsonData);` does this trick as well :).

Comment: Should this work for local JSON files? I keep getting this error in Chrome: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/test/settings.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https, isolated-app.`

Answer (score 10):

Posting this an an answer, because:

- it's what the user asking the question actually used as their solution
- it's cleaner to look at than require text, since it always does the JSON.parse() for you.

**[RequireJS has a JSON plugin](https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins)**. The syntax is simply:

```
require(['json!someData.json'], function(data){
  ...
})
```

Comment: for those that find this unclear, ["json!/some/ajax/endpoint"] works great too

Comment: Is it possible to load local file?

Comment: @erik I normally use a webserver (via gulp) to develop locally so always load a http:// or https:// URL. I'd recommend you do the same. If you're asking about file:// URLs, I don't know.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for file URLs. I keep getting this error in Chrome: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/test/settings.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https, isolated-app.`