# How re load json file via requirejs?

Tags: javascript, json, requirejs

I'm trying to load json file vie requirejs like the following:

```
'use strict';

require.config({
    paths: {
        config: '../../configs/config.json'
    }
});

require([
    'spec/test.js',
], function() {
    mocha.run();
});
```

To be possible require it like the following:

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {    
    var configJSON = require('config');
});
```

But unfortunately I get the following error:

```
<PATH_TO_PROJECT>/configs/config.json.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: Are you running node.js or in the browser?

Comment: I'm running in a browser

Comment: I think this might then cover everything you need to know: [requirejs load static JSON file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314019/requirejs-load-static-json-file)

Comment: I tried this. but get the following error `Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

Comment: Are you running this as a local file or something? :S

Comment: yes I need to load local json file for my mocha test

Comment: In that case you will be forced to use a http file server (or 'hack' your way around it using JSONP style files, but that's really not advisable). If you have python installed the following is an easy one: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python