# Pass In Config Values to JS File

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript file, and I would like to pass in a few config values to my JS file. I originally thought of using an .INI file, but I found out that the browser cannot access these System Config values. Does anyone have any suggestions to alternatives?

Comment: in what context do you use this js-file? and where should the config file come from?

Comment: Are you talking about accessing System Configuration (msconfig) from javascript?

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify. My JS file makes a bunch of calls to various endpoints. Instead of updating the endpoints in the JS, I want to do the updates in a separate config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I store my configuration in a separate JSON file and load that into the app as a configuration object.

See this answer for examples on how to do this using Require.js or jQuery: [requirejs load static JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314019/requirejs-load-static-json-file)