# How to integrate requirejs in existing vuejs project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, requirejs

I'm trying to load JSON data inside my vue template.
To fetch JSON data, I'm using the `require` instead of `import`. So I can make set any dynamic UUID in the future for local JSON file name. But this resulting to error of `error  'require' is not defined`

```
<script>
export default {
    name: "BloePage",
    data() {
        return {
            blogcontent: require(`../content_files/UUDD_WWAA_EEFF_EWWW_AAWW.json`)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

As I got to know from web sources. To use `require` in vuejs project. I need integrate `requirejs` in my existing vuejs project. I searched for this a lot. but didn't found any straight forward way of doing this...

Any Suggestions or Solution?

Comment: should help:  https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#cjsmodule

Comment: and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314019/how-do-i-use-requirejs-to-load-a-static-json-file

Answer (score -1):

Node.js's `require` and RequireJS do not work the same way. You cannot use RequireJS to load JSON, synchronously, from a URL.

If you want to fetch data from a URL, use Ajax.

You can find an example of how to do this [in the Vue manual](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html):

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      blogcontent: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get('../content_files/UUDD_WWAA_EEFF_EWWW_AAWW.json')
      .then(response => (this.blogcontent = response))
  }
})
```

Comment: Some one down voted this answer and my question too. I tried axios but it doesn't work with local JSON files.

Comment: Nothing works with local files, that's standard browser security. Web applications need to be hosted on web servers.